# How to align objects in draw.io?

Tags: app.diagrams.net

Is there a possibility to select multiple objects and then i) align them such that they have a common center line and ii) distribute them evenly, such that the vertical spacing between them is evenly?

[image: Visual representation of the question]

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Select the vertices, select "Arrange" on the right-hand side panel, click the alignment option you required.

[image]

Comment: I didn't even notice those tabs, thanks! One more question: the distribute positions all center lines at equal distance, which would be nice. It would be nicer however, to have equal spacing between objects, which is not the same in my example above where the objects have not all the same height. Is this also possible?

Comment: Note (as least as of Aug 2019) that the alignment controls don't appear until you've more than one object selected

Answer (score 0):

Shapes can be aligned only. It is not possible to align lines.