# Draw.io align objects with respect to each other

Tags: app.diagrams.net

I'm trying to find the functionality to align objects against each other in draw.io. According to the documentation, and based on the directions in [How to align objects in draw.io?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/73518/how-to-align-objects-in-draw-io) it should just be there. However, it's not there when I try to use it.

[image: Draw.in arrange menu]

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I've worked it out myself. First select two or more objects, then you get the option to align. Easy huh!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is an issue that cannot be reproduced.

Comment: Please note: This isn't draw.io support, so calling a previous question here a "ticket" is a misnomer.